# How to use my custom-built library with "*.aar" extension in react native project

Tags: android-studio, react-native, aar

I have a library in android studio with *.arr extension.

I create a react-native project and add this library to android studio.

It added to android studio but how can I import it and use it in my components. (I think it had to be in node_modules files in order to accessible in react native components).

I write this library in android studio, and it is private and naturally doesn't have NPM link for install.

I saw some packages using 'react-native link' for installing. Is it related to my problem?

how can i use my custom-built library in my components?